# How to disable unused LAN ports on Fortigate

Tags: fortigate, fortinet

I know I can set the administrative status of WAN/DMZ ports to down to disable them, but I can only see how to set the entire internal interface up/down. Is there a way to set individual LAN ports down so someone cannot plug into them and access the network?

Comment: What type of fortinet device is it?

Comment: It is a Fortigate-60D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's look like that the`internal-switch-mode` is set as *switch¹* (by default). That means that all port on the **internal** interface are configured as they are only one:

> Switch mode combines FortiGate unit interfaces into one switch with
>   one address. Interface mode gives each internal interface its own
>   address.²

so, as I understand, if in system global configuration you set: `internal-switch-mode interface`, you shall configure each port independently, so you will able to reconfigure port 1 and 2 then disable the other as @David say.

NB ***Before*** switching modes, all configuration settings for the interfaces affected by the switch **must** be set to defaults.²

Ref:

1. [Fotigate "Interface" command CLI document](http://docs-legacy.fortinet.com/fgt/handbook/cli_html/index.html#page/FortiOS%25205.0%2520CLI/config_system.24.034.html)
2. [Fotigate "Global config" command CLI document](http://docs-legacy.fortinet.com/fgt/handbook/cli_html/index.html#page/FortiOS%25205.0%2520CLI/config_system.24.031.html)

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished through the GUI by

1. navigating to System -> Network -> interface
2. select the desired interface
3. select edit for that interface
4. change "Administrative Access" to Down.

This can also be accomplished through the CLI with these commands:

> config system interface
>
> edit (desired interface)
>
> set status down

(this works for devices running fortios)

Comment: That lets me turn down the entire internal interface (all 8 internal ports on the Fortigate-60D), but not individual ports on the internal interface.

Comment: Furthering on my comment, I have a Fortigate device at a client site. I have two devices connected to internal ports 1 and 2. I want to disable ports 3-7 so that they are unusable.

Comment: See @gio900's answer for how to take the device off internal switch mode

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this by GUI, it can be done only by CLI:

config system virtual-switch

edit internal

```
config port

  edit internal3
    set status down
  next

  edit internal4
     set status down
  next

end
```

end

end

Of course internal-switch-mode must be set to interface first.

Hope this helps.

Wlodek W.